# How to disable V-validate for my whole website

Tags: c#, forms, validation, vue.js

I have a form that uses v validates (vue.js validation). I'm trying to implement some server side validation also, but am having trouble testing it as the client side validation kicks in before the server side does, so I'm not able to see if it's working as it should.

Instead of turning off the v validation for each individual input, is there a way I can turn it off for the whole website?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can turn it off from your solution as per their [documentation](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/). However, You can remove **data-vv-scope** attribute from the form.